# jasper reports - passing empty parameter values from one subreport to the next

Tags: reporting-services, jasper-reports

I am creating a nested sub-report by passing parameters as below:

Main Report --> Subreport1 --> Subreport2

Main report passes parameter A to subreport 1
Subreport1 passes parameter B to subreport 2

If during execution, the parameter B has no value (i.e. a SQL query does not return a value at all for parameter B), then the report execution fully stops at that point. Even if there are subsequent values of parameter A for which there are non-empty query results for parameter B, the report does not get executed.

How do we ensure that the report execution continues even when parameter B is empty? I am using ireport designer for report design.

Thanks in advance
Venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

You will need at least one record for the sub report to continue executing I would suggest you modify your SQL query to return an empty row even if zero rows matches.

check out this question for more details on how to accomplish this:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41067/getting-select-to-return-a-constant-value-even-if-zero-rows-match